# qdbus is Segmentation faulting

Tags: qdbus

I'm using KTimeTracker to monitor my time on different projects. I have a PHP script that periodically runs to give me an idea on how long I've worked in the day.

The PHP script used to connect to KtimeTracker using qdbus to save to file and then use qdbus to
export the CSV file.

For those that wonder why I'm bothering with this setup, I work from home and need to monitor my time to ensure I'm working the right number of hours.

The script worked perfectly well for quite a while but has recently started failing when using qdbus. The simplest call to qdbus is :
`qdbus org.kde.ktimetracker /KTimeTracker saveAll`

The result of this is

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

`qdbus org.kde.ktimetracker /KTimeTracker`

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

`qdbus org.kde.ktimetracker`

```
/KTimeTracker
/MainApplication
/ktimetracker
/ktimetracker/MainWindow_1
/ktimetracker/MainWindow_1/actions
/ktimetracker/MainWindow_1/actions/file_open
/ktimetracker/MainWindow_1/actions/file_save
/ktimetracker/MainWindow_1/actions/options_configure
/ktimetracker/MainWindow_1/actions/start_new_session
/ktimetracker/MainWindow_1/actions/edit_history
/ktimetracker/MainWindow_1/actions/reset_all_times
/ktimetracker/MainWindow_1/actions/start
/ktimetracker/MainWindow_1/actions/stop
/ktimetracker/MainWindow_1/actions/focusSearchBar
/ktimetracker/MainWindow_1/actions/stopAll
/ktimetracker/MainWindow_1/actions/focustracking
/ktimetracker/MainWindow_1/actions/new_task
/ktimetracker/MainWindow_1/actions/new_sub_task
/ktimetracker/MainWindow_1/actions/delete_task
/ktimetracker/MainWindow_1/actions/edit_task
/ktimetracker/MainWindow_1/actions/edit_task_time
/ktimetracker/MainWindow_1/actions/mark_as_complete
/ktimetracker/MainWindow_1/actions/mark_as_incomplete
/ktimetracker/MainWindow_1/actions/export_dialog
/ktimetracker/MainWindow_1/actions/import_planner
/ktimetracker/MainWindow_1/actions/searchbar
/ktimetracker/MainWindow_1/actions/file_quit
/ktimetracker/MainWindow_1/actions/options_configure_keybinding
/ktimetracker/MainWindow_1/actions/options_show_statusbar
/ktimetracker/MainWindow_1/actions/options_configure_toolbars
/org
/org/kde
/org/kde/ktimetracker
```

I'm sure that I'm missing something simple but just can't see it. I've spent a few hours already Googling but have come up with nothing.

I don't know if these are of any value

```
sudo zypper search --provides qdbus
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...

S  | Name                   | Summary                                          | Type
---+------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+--------
i+ | libqt5-qdbus           | Command line client for communication over D-Bus | package
   | libqt5-qdbus-debuginfo | Debug information for package libqt5-qdbus       | package
i+ | libqt5-qttools         | Qt 5 QtTools Module                              | package

cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="openSUSE Tumbleweed"
# VERSION="20201114"
ID="opensuse-tumbleweed"
ID_LIKE="opensuse suse"
...

develop@bambam:~> bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.18(1)-release (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu)
...
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: I can get KtimeTracker to create the CSV if I use the dropdown menus so have a temporary workaround but I need to remember to create the file :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `qdbus` command with `qdbus-qt5`